# Pass dynamically generated directory name to Destination attribute of cffile tag

Tags: file-upload, coldfusion, cffile

I am struggling with the following cffile code. I am trying to pass a dynamically generated images directory, the name of which is stored in a session variable (one for each new member). I need to pass that name to the destination attribute of the cffile tag:

Heres my code for processing the file upload

```
<cfset mypath=expandpath('UserImages/UploadedImages/' & '#session.details.uimages#')>
<cffile action="upload" destination="#mypath#" nameconflict="makeunique"/>
```

The upload works fine if I replace the #session.details.uimages# with an actual directory name. Is, what I am trying to do, achieveable or is this not possible?

Any help, or guidance will be welcomed as I am tearing my hair out!

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: That should work fine. Dump my path and ensure its the correct location.

Answer (score 6):

If the directory doesn't exist, you need to create it first.

If uimages comes from the user, don't forget to first verify it is a valid directory name (and specifically, that it doesn't contain path traversal syntax, i.e. `..`).

Also, your [cffile](http://cfdocs.org/cffile-action-upload) lacked the filefield attribute, which is required.

Note as well the lack of hashes around the session variable - they are unnecessary.

```
<cfset MyPath = expandPath( 'UserImages/UploadedImages/' & session.details.uimages ) />

<cfif NOT DirectoryExists( MyPath )>
    <cfset DirectoryCreate( MyPath ) />
</cfif>

<cffile
    action       = "upload"
    destination  = "#MyPath#"
    nameconflict = "makeunique"
    filefield    = "name_of_field_to_upload_from"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for yur reply Peter. The code above has been implemented. It still doesn't work. I have been following Ramond Camden's blog at http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/11/11/Important-notes-about-ColdFusion-9s-new-multi-file-uploader

Comment: "It still doesn't work" is meaningless - _what_ doesn't work and _how_? i.e. What is the error message or unexpected result?

(Also, when you're following a blog post, state that in the original question, along with which version of CF you are using.)

Comment: Ray has a newer/complete tutorial for this here: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2010/3/5/ColdFusion-9-Multifile-Uploader--Complete-Example

Comment: Sorry for hiccup. I am using CF10 (hosted). 'Doesn't work' means selected file isn't uploaded. Code works by replacing session variable to a static name. This code is called from a page with this code:

    <cffileupload url="uploadall.cfm" name="files">

Destination attr of cffile on processing page, uploadall.cfm doesn't like variables passed to it from outside that page. If a new variable name is created on processing page, the code works fine. I wonder its something to do with tracking the session variables across pages! Peter I am new to this so please bear with me and advise accordingly.